# How to know the length of a video?

Tags: nautilus, video

I've this videos inside a folder, and I would like to know how to know each one's length without the need of open them.

If I select a video, in the bottom right corner I get the file size.

Where's the length? Even clicking on "properties" doesn't show me the video's length...

If I set the viewing option as a list (inside nautilus), length isn't an option.

Have tried searching in this forum with the keywords "show video length" and there's no result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04, the properties window, under the audio/video shows the length.

1. Select your video. Right click on it and choose properties.
2. Select the Audio/Video tab.
3. The duration is displayed.

See screenshot below:

[image]